# How to pass json string generated on server side and use it as aparameter in javascript on client side in MVC

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Hello everyone this will be my first question!

So basically i want to pass serialized array from server side to client side and then use it as a parameter in JS. For now im sending it as a regular string by viewModel and trying to inject it by using @Html.Raw() as below but it doesn't work:

```
        var table = $('#shipments').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "GetShipmentsAH",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
                $(nRow).attr('shipID', aData[0]);
            },
            "aoColumns": @Html.Raw(Model.ShipmentsAoColJSon);
        });
```

This is a value of Model.ShipmentsAoColJSon:

> [{"sName":"ID","sDefaultContent":"","bSortable":true,"bSearchable":true,"sSearch":""},{"sName":"EAN","sDefaultContent":"","bSortable":true,"bSearchable":true,"sSearch":""},{"sName":"Serial","sDefaultContent":"","bSortable":true,"bSearchable":true,"sSearch":""},{"sName":"Nr","sDefaultContent":"","bSortable":true,"bSearchable":true,"sSearch":""},{"sName":"StoreUnitNr","sDefaultContent":"","bSortable":true,"bSearchable":true,"sSearch":""},{"sName":"FCode","sDefaultContent":"","bSortable":true,"bSearchable":true,"sSearch":""},{"sName":"ProdDesc","sDefaultContent":"","bSortable":true,"bSearchable":true,"sSearch":""}]

When i just copy paste it it straight to code it works fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: You could set up a web api that will serve up that data, then consume it with an ajax call.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work" ?  You should be able to view the HTML that is emitted by MVC and compare it to the page when you paste the JSON in manually.  Are there any differences?

Comment: Ok i think i find a source of a problem. Script was stored in external .js file when i copy pasted it directly to html <script></script> tag it woked. Is seems that @Html can be used only on main html page. Bu what is possible solution when i still wanted to store my scripts in external files?

Answer (score 0):

I found a source of a problem. Script was stored in external .js file when i copy pasted it directly to html  tag it worked. Is seems that @Html razor can be used only on main html page but no in js files. To handle that i wrote this in my Html:

var ShipAoColJSon = @Html.Raw(Model.ShipAoColJSon);

And then passit to js. file:

```
var table = $('#shipments').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "GetShipmentsAH",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
        $(nRow).attr('shipID', aData[0]);
    },
    "aoColumns": ShipAoColJSon
});
```